# Power amplifier efficiency confusion

Tags: power

Assuming I am considering A single stage class A amplifier, as we know the efficiency of the amplifier is AC power out/quiescent Dc power in, but the problem is when signal is applied shouldn't the formula be ac power out/instantaneous dc power out at that time? Because when the signal is applied the input dc power should be more than the dc quiescent power, so the actual (instantenious)dc input power at that time should be more and that's the original input power, not the quiescent input power should be considered as input power. Isn't it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old [nutmeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutmeg_(association_football))..

The DC power into a class A amplifier is voltage x current. Now, if the current is a DC quiescent value superimposed with an AC value (representing the signal) you might think that DC voltage x AC current might factor into things. Well, it doesn't and what you find is that the DC power in is DC voltage in x DC current in. Where the DC current in is the average value of the DC current.

In other words, for a class A amplifier, no matter what signal you have as your input (within reason of course), the DC power taken by the amplifier is constant.

If you overdrive the input and get a nasty distorted waveform shape out then all bets are off.

Comment: I've seen many books they are considering the input dc current as quiescent current (I_dc=I_bias+I_collector)taken by the amplifier, if we take the average value of the input dc current , it makes sense dc voltage* average dc current as input dc power, but according to their formula the power is = input dc voltage* quiescent dc current. But I think they are different, isn't it?

Comment: @Sayan For a class A amplifier the quiescent current is the average current.

Comment: I thought quiescent current is the current which is supplied by the battery in quiescent mode, means it should be I_bias+I_collector in quiescent mode, so I was wrong, right?

Comment: For a class A amplifier, the quiescent current is always the average current that is drawn from the supply irrespective of signal amplitude (within reason). How many times do I need to repeat this?

Comment: thanks, don't get angry.